# mysql insert/update multi rows in one call

Tags: mysql, insert-update

In my MySql table I want to insert a number of rows. Some of the rows exist and these should only be updated.

So my table looks like this:

> **mytable:** Id (key) | Value (varchar)

And my query is something like this:

> INSERT INTO keycomp_mytable (key, value) VALUES
>   ("k1","foo"),("k2","bar"),("k3","baz"),("k4","qux")

If one key exists allready, say k2, then that value should just be updated. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into the [insert on duplicate](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) syntax.

Note that this only works if the duplicate value is a UNIQUE key or a primary key (which in your question looks like this is the case).

Comment: Ive allready checked the INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Syntax but seems it is only concerning updating/inserting one row at a time... Ive tried:
INSERT INTO keycomp_candidate_score (Id, Value) VALUES ("1","2"),("4","5") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE but it gives error

Comment: The linked page includes an example of using it for multiple values. Note that you should be including what fields get updated. I.e. INSERT INTO keycomp_candidate_score (Id, Value) VALUES ("1","2"),("4","5") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Value = VALUES(Value)

Comment: Perfect, Value = VALUES(Value) was what Ive been missing - thanks a lot!